# apt install stuck on mirrordirector

Tags: raspbian-jessie, software-installation, apt, packages

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt show rsync
Package: rsync
Version: 3.1.1-3
Maintainer: Paul Slootman <paul@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 645 kB
Depends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8), libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.46-8), libc6 (>= 2.15), libpopt0 (>= 1.14), lsb-base (>= 3.2-14), base-files (>= 4.0.1)
Suggests: openssh-client, openssh-server
Breaks: duplicity (<< 0.6.11)
Homepage: http://rsync.samba.org/
Priority: optional
Section: net
Download-Size: 373 kB
APT-Sources: http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
Description: fast, versatile, remote (and local) file-copying tool
 rsync is a fast and versatile file-copying tool which can copy locally
 and to/from a remote host. It offers many options to control its behavior,
 and its remote-update protocol can minimize network traffic to make
 transferring updates between machines fast and efficient.
 .
 It is widely used for backups and mirroring and as an improved copy
 command for everyday use.
 .
 This package provides both the rsync command line tool and optional
 daemon functionality.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install rsync
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rsync
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
Need to get 373 kB of archives.
After this operation, 645 kB of additional disk space will be used.
0% [Connecting to mirrordirector.raspbian.org (93.93.128.193)]^Cpi@raspberrypi:~ $ ^C
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get rsync
E: Invalid operation rsync
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install rsync
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rsync
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
Need to get 373 kB of archives.
After this operation, 645 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main rsync armhf 3.1.1-3
  Cannot initiate the connection to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/r/rsync/rsync_3.1.1-3_armhf.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: It's a transient error. Reboot, check your network connectivity and retry.

Comment: No, it's very persistent.  Network is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an obsolete ancient OS which is unsupported and will NEVER have any updates.

Repositories have been archived.

If, for some reason, you want to use Jessie it is possible to modify the sources. If you search this site you will find others who have done this.